# Stan error: require unconstrained variable declaration. found simplex

Tags: r, stan

In Stan, I get the following error:

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
require unconstrained variable declaration. found simplex.

ERROR at line 48
 46:    for (j in 1:records) {  
 47:            real phenology_predictor;
 48:            simplex[7] pi;
                        ^
```

I don't quite understand what is the problem. When I used `real pi[7]` instead of `simplex[7] pi`, I got different error:

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
no matches for function name="categorical_log"
    arg 0 type=int
    arg 1 type=real[1]
available function signatures for categorical_log:
0.  categorical_log(int, vector) : real
1.  categorical_log(int[1], vector) : real
unknown distribution=categorical

ERROR at line 63
 62:    
 63:                    Y[j] ~ categorical(pi);
                                      ^
 64:
```

which I don't understand either... My whole code:

```
data {
    int sites;
    int records;
    int Y[records];
    vector[records] yday;
    int site[records];
}
transformed data {
    int M[sites];
}
parameters {
    real<lower=0,upper=1> psi;
    real<lower=0,upper=1000> phi_phen_scale;
    real phi_alpha;
    real q_date;
    real q_date2;
    real q_site[sites];
}
model {
    real p[records];
    real q[records];

// priors
phi_phen_scale ~ normal(0, 10);
phi_alpha ~ normal(0, 10);
q_date ~ normal(0, 10);
q_date2 ~ normal(0, 10);

// vectorized
M ~ bernoulli(psi);
q_site ~ normal(0, 10);

for (j in 1:records) {  
    real phenology_predictor;
    simplex[7] pi;

    phenology_predictor <- q_date * yday[j] + q_date2 * yday[j]^2;
    p[j] <- M[site[j]] * inv_logit(phi_alpha + phi_phen_scale * phenology_predictor);
    q[j] <- inv_logit(q_site[site[j]] + phenology_predictor);

    pi[1] <- 1-p[j] + p[j]*(1-q[j])^6; 
    pi[2] <- p[j]*q[j]  ;   
    pi[3] <- p[j]*(1-q[j])*q[j];
    pi[4] <- p[j]*(1-q[j])^2*q[j];
    pi[5] <- p[j]*(1-q[j])^3*q[j];
    pi[6] <- p[j]*(1-q[j])^4*q[j];
    pi[7] <- p[j]*(1-q[j])^5*q[j];

    Y[j] ~ categorical(pi);

}

}
```

Comment: Constrained local parameters, such as simplexes, cannot be declared inside the model block because they are not checked. So, you should just declare pi to be a plain vector of length 7, like ```vector[7] pi;```. Nevertheless, pi needs to be on the simplex in order to be an admissible argument to the categorical function. It is not obvious that your construction of pi guarantees that all seven elements are non-negative and sum to unity, but perhaps that is the cause and they only violate those constraints due to numerical inaccuracy. If so, you could try renormalizing pi before passing it.

Comment: @BenGoodrich, the pi should actually sum to 1 by definition. Are you suggesting that I might have to renormalize just because of the rounding errors? Is it such a big deal? Please post this as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constrained local parameters, such as simplexes, cannot be declared inside the model block because they are not checked. So, you should just declare `pi` to be a plain vector of length 7, like `vector[7] pi;`. Nevertheless, pi needs to be on the simplex in order to be an admissible argument to the categorical function.

If it is the case that symbolically pi is non-negative and sums to 1, then it is a question of making sure that numerically they are sufficiently close to non-negative and sum to something that is sufficiently close to 1. I'm not sure what the numerical tolerance is for a simplex in Stan but there is some wiggle room. If numerical error is the problem then doing `pi <- pi / sum(pi);` before passing `pi` to the `categorical` function may help.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I have completed your answer using your comment above.